# RxJava toMultiMap not working with room database Query

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to get a map of messages, with an author id key like this:

```
Map<Long, Collection<Message>>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
messageViewModel.getAll()
                    .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
                    .toMultimap(Message::getAuthorId)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onSuccess);

private void onSuccess(Map<Long, Collection<Message>> longCollectionMap) {
    Collection<Message> messages = longCollectionMap.get(0);
}
```

The method messageViewModel.getAll() returns:

```
Flowable<List<Message>>
```

So then I convert it to a Flowable stream(Flowable::fromIterable) so it can emit one item at a time instead of the whole list, and then I do the mapping with the "toMultiMap"

The onSuccess method is never called, I don't know what is wrong here. If I don't use toMultiMap (and do the corresponding modifications to the code) it works, so the problem must be the toMultiMap method.

But when I try this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Flowable.fromIterable(list)
                    .toMultimap(String::length)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onSuccess);

 private void onSuccess(Map<Integer,Collection<String>> integerCollectionMap) {
    Collection<String> strings = integerCollectionMap.get(1);
}
```

This works! The only difference is that this one does not call the room database to fetch the items for the iterable.

Also the documentation says:

> Note that this operator requires the upstream to signal {@code onComplete} for the accumulated map to be emitted.

This confuses me. As the Flowable class does not have a subscribe method with onComplete as a parameter, and it is not used on the second case I showed above, yet it works.

Please help me out this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for anyone going through the same or similar problem.

First of all, I had to debug to see if the mapping was actually done or not at all. For that I just debugged it starting from the toMultiMap method. Then I found out that the mapping was actually done, so the problem was that the result was not returning.

Reading more about RxJava I realized the cause of the problem. The first call:

```
messageViewModel.getAll()
```

Was returning

```
Flowable<List<Message>>
```

This means that this source will emit 0 to n elements, in this case "Lists" of Message. And indeed, it emmitted the list of Message and after that the mapping was done. But it was not returning anything, because it was waiting for more "Lists" to come up from the source.

You have to remember that a Flowable or Observable, could potentially emit infinite elements. The difference with doing Flowable.fromIterable is that fromIterable will stop, or signal that the stream is over after emitting the last element of the iterable that is passed as an argument, meaning that the rest of the sequence of methods calls will not wait for more elements to come and the result will be returned.

So the solution was changing the return type of the messageViewModel.getAll() to:

```
Single<List<Message>>
```

So now it will either emit 1 item, the list of messages, or an error. So after the one element is emitted no more will come and the other methods on the chain will execute and return the value.

However the "toMultiMap" method does not work with "Single", there is no such a thing on the Single class. So you have to convert it to a flowable, so I did this:

```
.flatMapPublisher(Flowable::fromIterable)
```

So at the end the code end up like this:

```
messageViewModel.getAll() //Returns Single<List<Message>>
                .flatMapPublisher(Flowable::fromIterable) // Creates a flowable from List<Message>
                .toMultimap(Message::getAuthorId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onSuccess);
```

Very nice and clean code, it takes some time to understand how the reactive approach works but it is definitely worth it. Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
Map<Long, Collection<Message>> myMap = messageViewModel.getAll()
    .flatMap(message ->
        Observable.fromIterable(message)
            .toMultimap(Message::getAuthorId)
            .toObservable());
```